# Gezerah Shema Yaverenu Daaled Amos- no megillah, lulav, or shofar on shabbos as a gezerah

Tags: shabbat, megillat-esther, lulav-etrog-arba-minim, shofar, hotzaa-carrying-reshuyot

Why is the Gezerah that maybe he will carry a lulav, shofar, megillah on shabbos for 4 amos in the Rishus Harabim? How did it get there? It should be gezerah that maybe he will take it out of the house, Rishus Hayuchid, and then carry it to learn how to blow, read, shake, etc.?? So it is the Averah of Hotzuah, not Carrying that should be the source of the gezerah?

The gezerah of maybe he will carry it 4 amos implies he is walking in the street and suddenly comes across this object and suddenly decides he needs to learn how to use it? Very unlikely. Are we dealing with a poor, homeless person who has to resort to finding this object? Very strange set of circumstances. Please give me a cogent, logical answer.

Comment: Tosafos addresses this in a few places. For example https://www.sefaria.org/Tosafot_on_Rosh_Hashanah.29b.10.1?vhe=Vilna_Edition&lang=he

Comment: TY Harel! I checked the different cites. Basically, tosfos says it is less likely to occur from RHaychid to RHarabim because it is more recognizable so he wont cross the threshold. Whereas, he may pick up the lulav in the RHarabim and start to walk. Rashi even brings in Rashi on Megillah 4b:21:2
ויעבירנה ארבע אמות - ואפילו לן בשדה ומגילה בידו יש לגזור על הדבר:

Comment: TY Harel! I checked the different cites. Basically, tosfos says it is less likely to occur from RHaychid to RHarabim because it is more recognizable so he wont cross the threshold. Whereas, he may pick up the lulav in the RHarabim and start to walk. Rashi even brings in Rashi on Megillah 4b:21:2
ויעבירנה ארבע אמות - ואפילו לן בשדה ומגילה בידו יש לגזור על הדבר: But I have dificulty understanding how this is even "normal" or "possible". Generally, Rabbanim dont make a gezerah that is Lo Schiach. How is this Schiach that a person is lying in a field with a megillah erev shabbos??

Comment: There are dozens of examples of Chazal making gezeiros on cases that are extremely unlikely to happen. Would you like some examples? I don't see this as any different. That's a separate question, why [the gemarra says](https://www.sefaria.org/search?q=%D7%A9%D7%9B%D7%99%D7%97%20%D7%9C%D7%90%20%D7%92%D7%96%D7%A8%D7%95&tab=text&tpathFilters=Talmud|Talmud%20Commentary&tvar=1&tsort=relevance&svar=1&ssort=relevance) if it's not likely to happen they won't make a gezeira, yet we see many exceptions o that.

Comment: TY. I see one has to have the Status of a Tanna or Amora to see where to be Gozer and where not and , perhaps , it not dependent on our simple view of the Universe but something else hidden from  our ordinary eyes.